# Database First with Multiple Tables with Foreign Keys in a Single View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have two tables `department` and `teacher` like this:

`Department` table (`DeptID` is the primary key)

```
DeptID | DeptName
 1         P
 2         C
 3         M
```

`Teacher` table (`DeptID` is a foreign key)

```
   DeptID | TeacherName
    1         ABC
    1         PQR
    2         XYZ
```

I have used database first approach to create a single model out of these two tables. I want to display both details in a single view like this:

```
TeacherName | DeptName
    ABC          P
    PQR          P
    XYZ          C
```

I tried to create controllers using scaffolding but it would provide views and CRUD operations for a single table in the model.

Is there any method using which I can map these two tables together in a single view ? or is it possible (easily achievable) when I use different models for each table in the database ?

Comment: what is in your model , can u provide code

Comment: can u give model code so i can understand ur question better and I know db first

Comment: I can't understand how did u end up with one model when you have two tables with db first

Comment: no prob man take ur time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create Viewmodel.

```
public class DepartmentTeacher
{
  public int DeptID   {get;set;}
  public string DeptName {get;set;}
  public int TeachID  {get;set;}
  public string TeachName {get;set;}
}

    using (var db = new SchoolContext())

{
                var query = (from tc in db.Teacher
                             join dp in db.Department on tc.DeptID equals dp.DeptID
                             //where st.STUDENT_ID == Customer_Id maybe you need
                             select new
                             {
                                dp.DeptName,
                                tc.TeachName

                             });

         foreach (var item in query)
                {
                    DepartmentTeacher.DeptName = item.DeptName;
                    DepartmentTeacher.TeachName = item.TeachName;
                }


}

 return View(DepartmentTeacher);
```

You can use every process this viewmodel.However you have to description this Viewmodel on your view page.